# Create Upsert Function ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, upsert

im new in asp.net and i don't know if this is possible. How do i create an `UPSERT` function in ASP.NET C# Where you Update an Entity and if it does not exist it automatically insert the row.

i have this collection/entity

name `travelRequest`

```
namespace TRS.Entities
{
   [Table("travelRequest")]
    public class travelRequest
    {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int travelRequestID { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual IList<trTravelDest> trTravelDest { get; set; }
    //...
    }
```

with a virtual list `trTravelDest` containing

```
namespace TRS.Entities
{
    [Table("trTravelDest")]
    public class trTravelDest
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int trTravelDestID { get; set; }
        public int travelRequestID { get; set; } //fk from travelRequest table
        public virtual travelRequest travelRequest { get; set; }
      //...
    }
}
```

I use this function `Update(travelRequest travelRequest)` in updating a request my problem is when i add a new row in the `trTravelDest` it will disregard or it wont insert. how can i make it automatically detect if the `travelRequest.trTravelDest` `Update(parameter)` has a new row on it and insert it automatically.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(travelRequest travelRequest)
{
if (TryUpdateModel(travelRequest))
 {try {
db.SaveChanges();
 // updateSuccessfull = true;
} catch{
 //  updateSuccessfull = false;}
}
var data = db.travelRequest.Find(travelRequest.travelRequestID);
return View("EditTr",data);
}
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to check the ID field of your entity. I'm going to assume that you have this and that you retrieve your entities propertly. If your ID is 0, then it doesn't exist in the database, which you then insert into the database.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework? From EF6+ you have handy .AddOrUpdate() method

Comment: I am wondering. I am assuming that traveldest is one of many places in a travel request. Isn't it the case that different travel requests can have the same traveldest? If so then you shoul not use a foreign key in traveldest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx)-method is exactly what you need.

> Adds or updates entities by key when SaveChanges is called. Equivalent
>   to an "upsert" operation from database terminology. This method can be
>   useful when seeding data using Migrations.

You use the method like this:

```
context.TravelRequests.AddOrUpdate(
    x => x.trTravelDestID,    // Assuming the travelRequest are unique on this key   
    travelRequestToUpsert);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The first parameter tells the function on what property it can determine how objects are unique. A primary key is ideal here. The second (and third, ...) are the objects you want to upsert.

Comment: db.travelRequest.AddOrUpdate(x => x.travelRequestID, travelRequest); db.SaveChanges();  ?? i will try to look on how to use the method. thanks for you response!